# failed to test create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, functional-testing

I am playing with rails 3.0.6 with ruby 1.9.2, 
the app is working on browser but not in testing..

1) I created a new rails application by "rails new myapp"

2) Generate a scaffold "rails generate scaffold user username:string hashed_password:string salt:string"

3) after that, i changed the users_controller a bit

```
  # POST /users
  # POST /users.xml
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        // change @user to usrs_url
        format.html { redirect_to(users_url, :notice => "User #{@user.username} was successfully created.") }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user, :status => :created, :location => @user }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /users/1
  # PUT /users/1.xml
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        // change @user to usrs_url
        format.html { redirect_to(users_url, :notice => "User #{@user.username} was successfully updated.") }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

4) so i try to modify tests as well:

```
 setup do
    @input_attributes = {
        :username               => 'username@goodmail.com',
        :password               => 'secret',
        :password_confirmation  => 'secret'
    }

    @user = users(:one)
  end

  test "should create user" do
    assert_difference('User.count') do
      post :create, :user => @input_attributes
    end

    assert_redirected_to users_path
  end

  test "should update user" do
    put :update, :id => @user.to_param, :user => @input_attributes
    assert_redirected_to users_path
  end
```

But the create and update tests failed

Can anyone let me know what had i done wrong?

Thanks

```
Loaded suite C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
F.....F
Finished in 5.628874 seconds.

  1) Failure:
test_should_create_user(UsersControllerTest) [test/functional/users_controller_test.rb:26]:
"User.count" didn't change by 1.
<3> expected but was
<2>.

  2) Failure:
test_should_update_user(UsersControllerTest) [test/functional/users_controller_test.rb:45]:
Expected block to return true value.

7 tests, 9 assertions, 2 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips



require 'digest/sha2'
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true

    validates_format_of :username, :with => /\A^[^\r\n@ ][^\r\n@ ]+@[^\r\n@ ]+[.][^\r\n@. ]+$\Z/i

    #password is a fake field
    validates :password, :confirmation => true
    validate :password_must_be_present

    attr_accessor :password_confirmation
    attr_reader :password

    def password=(password)
        if password.present?
            generate_salt
            self.hashed_password = self.class.encrypt_password(password, salt)
        end
    end

    class << self
        def encrypt_password(password, salt)
            Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(password + "shrimpy" + salt)
        end

        def authenticate(username, password)
            if user = find_by_username(username)
                if user.hashed_password == encrypt_password(password, user.salt)
                    user
                end
            end
        end
    end

    private
        def password_must_be_present
            errors.add(:password, "Missing password") unless hashed_password.present?
        end

        def generate_salt
            self.salt = self.object_id.to_s + rand.to_s
        end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

`assert_redirected_to user_path` is singular. You probably don't even have a singular `user` resource route defined. What you want there is probably `assert_redirected_to users_path` with a plural *users*.

Comment: you are right...what a sharp eye. my typo mistake....it was supposed to be users_path... i fixed it... but problem still existed..not able to run through tests

Comment: @shrimpy: Looks like you are mixing and matching `users_path` and `users_url`. I don't know for sure, but I bet you `assert_redirected_to` is just comparing the strings output from `url_for` since it doesn't have the context of a request/hostname to build the full URL from a path. Give it a shot…it's worth fixing one way or another.

Comment: it doesn`t work for me.... back to the error message, it complain about not able to save record and update record into database.... but i used sqlite3...hmm..shouldn`t be a problem.....confused...

Comment: Is your application working? If you're getting an error you should share it.